# KiCad Ngspice reports "unknown parameter (-1.244400E-04)"

Tags: operational-amplifier, kicad, ngspice

I am trying to run a simulation utilizing a CA3140 op-amp; here is my example:

[image]

It was fine before my dinner, but after I got back, my PC was stuck, then an error comes after my reboot.

It is always an error like this:

```
No compatibility mode selected!
Circuit: KiCad schematic
Error on line 0 :
**r.xu1.rb1 net-_r2-pad2_ xu1.10 1 tc=1.991040e-03 (-1.244400e-04)**
unknown parameter (-1.244400e-04) 
Background thread stopped with timeout = 0
Error: circuit not parsed.
```

I am using a CA3140 model from [Sborka.lib](https://github.com/kicad-spice-library/KiCad-Spice-Library/tree/master/Models/uncategorized/Bordodynovs%20Electronics%20Lib/sub/Sborka.lib) on GitHub.

I think this file contains some grammar issues; I manually picked CA3140 out from this file.

Here is the code:

```
.subckt CA3140 1 36 15 20 12
*START OF DECK
* +IN -IN OUT +VSS -VSS
*NODE: 1 36 15 20 12
*------INPUT STAGE-------
VOSBAL 7 29 3.00000000E-03
EU1 8 1 20 12 0.0001
EU2 8 7 5 12 -1
RB1 12 10 1 TC= 1.991040E-03 (-1.244400E-04)
IB4 10 12 1.000000E-06
RB3 12 5 8743.17 TC= 1.60000000E-03 
IB3 12 5 5.718750E-07
G1 12 1 10 12 1.025000E-05
G2 12 36 10 12 9.750000E-06
RDM 36 29 1.500000E+12
RCM 31 13 1.500000E+12
CDM 36 29 4.000000p
G5 31 13 36 31 6.66667E-13
G6 31 13 1 31 6.66667E-13
*------INTERMEDIATE STAGE-------
GDM 31 16 29 36 1
GCM 31 16 13 31 -1.58113883E-05
R1 31 16 3.16358380E+02
C1 31 16 6.45457E-11
VCP 23 31 100
VCM 24 31 -100
DD1 16 23 MD2
.MODEL MD2 D XTI=1P cjo=10f rs=1m
DD2 24 16 MD2
G3 31 6 16 31 -1.07249255E-06
R2 31 6 100000
C2 11 6 1.2E-11
RP1 31 20 3750
RP2 31 12 3750
*------OUTPUT STAGE-------
G4 31 11 6 31 -5.10867719E+01
ROUT 31 11 60
DD3 11 9 MD3
.MODEL MD3 D IS=10.0F XTI=1.0P N= 3.612647E-01 cjo=10f tt=0.1n rs=1m
DD4 9 11 MD4
.MODEL MD4 D IS=10.0F XTI=1.0P N= 8.028126E-01 cjo=10f  tt=0.1n rs=1m
EU6 9 31 2 31 1
RO1 11 26 20
FF1 31 28 VFF1 1
VFF1 26 2 0.0
FF2 31 20 VFF2 -1
VFF2 33 31 0.0
FF3 12 31 VFF3 -1
VFF3 31 27 0.0
DD8 27 28 MID
DD7 28 33 MID
.MODEL MID D XTI=1.000000F N=1 IS=10.000000F cjo=10f  rs=1m tt=0.1n
VP 20 22 -29.2613
VM 21 12 -29.3113
DD5 25 22 MID
DD6 21 17 MID
VP1 20 30 2.7501
VM1 32 12 .859456
DD9 2 30 MD9
DD10 32 15 MD9
.MODEL MD9 D XTI=1.000000F N=1 IS=10.000000F cjo=10f rs=1m tt=0.1n
HH1 25 2 POLY(2) VIC2 VIC1 0 1960 0 1540 0 0 0 0 0 0
HH2 2 17 POLY(2) VIC3 VIC1 0 -1960 0 -1540 0 0 0 0 0 0
VIC1 37 3 0.0
VIC2 2 14 0.0
VIC3 14 15 0.0
VPP 37 0 1
RPP 3 0 100.0K
RO3 15 20 200.0MEG
RO2 15 12 200.0MEG
.ends
```

I think the error comes from the line `RB1 12 10 1 TC= 1.991040E-03 (-1.244400E-04)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's meant to be the second temperature coefficient then, according to the ng-spice manual, try converting that to:

```
RB1 12 10 1 TC1= 1.991040E-03 tc2=-1.244400E-04
```

If it's meant to be an alternative first temperature coefficient then try adding a semicolon right before the opening bracket:

```
RB1 12 10 1 TC= 1.991040E-03 ; (-1.244400E-04)
```

Though, looking through the manual, the syntax should be `tc1=... tc2=...`, or `tce=` but, maybe it accepts `tc` as an alternative spelling.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I get better understanding from your reply, I also realize I didn't set  the 'compatibility mode' as `PSpice and LTSpice`, the model works even without changing. But your advice is very much make sense.